# How to achieve this pattern/spread out effect in Photoshop/Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, effects, brush

I tried to imitate this effect in Illustrator using scatter brush but didn't achieve it. Does anyone know how to do this? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: With both applications, my first try would be with a scatter brush.

Comment: @Joonas I tried scatter brush, but if you look closely, the scatter pieces are not uniform. I am not sure how this is achieved. Maybe scatter brush+some sort of PS filter?

Comment: In both Illustrator and Photoshop, you got some brush settings you can randomize, which makes the brush strokes non-uniform. Basically you'll probably want to make like a few different brushes with different amounts of spacing, different max brush sizes, no scatter at all just lot of spacing, perhaps one brush that isn't perfectly round. In Photoshop `Jitter` setting is basically the randomize setting. Like `Size Jitter` for instance. In Illustrator you just gotta select `Random` in the brush settings for each setting you want to be random.

Comment: You could make this without the scatter setting, but it will help you fill out the bigger areas so you don't have to be brushing the same area for minutes to fill it up. Photoshop doesn't give you the option to randomize spacing, but size jitter, wide spacing and irregular brush strokes can solve that.

Answer (score 2):

A ten months old case, lifted on the top by the system. User @Theribos has already noticed that this is a mirrored pattern. We use it in Photoshop. There the job is easier.

Because the result is strictly black & white, it's easily traced to vector domain in Illustrator, if needed.

First have a white background. Make onto it the upper half or more and mirror it.  The actual drawing is done with using different black scatter brushes. Some greyness and apparent blurriness do not harm.

An example:

[image]

Apply Gaussian Blur

[image]

If you want some small dots stay surely well visible, you can paint them more. Do not blur them:

[image]

Goto Image > Adjustments > Treshold to create the blocky BW image:

[image]

Do the mirroring. One way to do it is copying, pasting and flipping manually:

- decide where you want the mirror line to be
- take the rectangular selection tool, select the upper half area
- copy and paste it in place; a new layer is generated automatically
- drag the selection upside down in the new layer. Or goto Edit > Transform > Flip vertically and drag the result to its place.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the image it seems a mirrored type of graphic. So I would try to paint (half the graphic; upper/lower half) in a vector programm --> splatters, dots aligned on a curve. Duplicate it and switch/mirror it. Export it as a bitmap > pixelgraphics

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried scatter brush in "Difference" mode? I think I can see the brush splats overlapping and subtracting from each other, like boolean shapes - the exact effect that a difference brush achieves.

Answer (score 0):

That pattern is symmetrical across a horizontal centerline.  And looking to the left, where the dots become individually visible, I find them to be very regular.  I think you're looking at the output of a postscript program that's been post-processed in, e.g. Pshop, to create the symmetrical flop.

I did get something vaguely similar in Pshop by using various sizes of brush tool with the airbrush feature, loadable textures, and overspraying (see below).  It's not your example pattern, but I can see how you could get there with experimentation.  The postscript program would probably be quicker, though.

[image]